# EF CodeFirst on Existing database

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am new to EF CodeFirst and trying to build relations between entities.

I've three tables and their relationship are as follows:

[image]

When I pass UserID I should get all the provider details of Organizations for which this user belongs to.

How to  build the entities and their relations for this scenario in CodeFirst(fluent API) approach? I am using EF CodeFirst on existing database. So these three tables already exists in Database.

Any inputs or pointers will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use EF Power Tools. It has Reverse Engineer option that will create a model for an exisiting database. If you want to configure your model with fluent API instead of attributes you can use the above to get you to a starting point where you would manually convert whatever needs to be converted.